# 'Car Home' in HTC Hero, Android 2.1

Tags: 2.1-eclair, htc-hero

I've just had my HTC Hero upgraded to Android 2.1, and I have heard about the Car Home function, which sounds great for when I use the new Google Maps Navigation in my car. However, this doesn't seem to be on my phone. Is that because of HTC installing HTC Sense? If so, can I get Car Home back again?

Comment: That app might not be available for the Hero, it is up to HTC and Sprint if they are going to include it in a release. What was the function of Car Home, what does it do? There might be something you can download or do to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the marketplace have a look at 'CarUI' similar but not identical.  Might have to root our Heros to get it, as it probably only compatible with 2.2 *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some alternatives, such as [Car Dashboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.mandaria.cardashboardfree&feature=search_result), which is a Car Home replacement app.

*Discalimer: I am the developer of this application*

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the following link:
http://androidforums.com/htc-desire/177579-froyo-car-panel-desire-htc-navigation-panel.html

The first post should have links to three different "Car Home" applications: Google Car Home, Google Car Launcher, and HTC Navigation Panel.  You will need to either go to this site on your phone and click the links or download the .apk and transfer it to your phone.  After reading a little more down the page it seems if you choose the Google one then you need to install both not just one of them.

I haven't tried these on my Hero yet (I will tonight after work) but in my experience trying to install apks either works or it doesn't - so give these a shot and see if any of them work.  If anyone has had different experience installing non-market apk's please sound off in the comments.

I also just found this page:
http://geekfor.me/hero/downloads/fresh21removedapks/

These are apps that are removed from the fresh ROM 2.1 for the Hero.  As you can see from the list the HTC Navigation Panel is in there.  However I don't know if you need to be on fresh ROM for these to work.

All that said, Byran's Car Dashboard look like a pretty cool replacement if you don't need the official Google or HTC car app.